# Calendar Controls, Event Handler for Load Event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, calendar, selectionchanged

I have been working on this for quite a while now. My code will show all the different ways and things that I have tried to get the problem fixed, but with no luck...so far. What I need to do is:

1. Start an event handler for the Load event of the form. Then add code to display the current date in the format shown above if the form is not being posted back.
2. Add a calendar control to the next paragraph, and set its Visible property to False so it's hidden when the form is first displayed.
3. Code an event handler for the Click event of the image button. This shold hide the image button and display the calendar control.
4. Code an event handler for the SelectionChanged event of the calendar control. This should get the selected date and display it in the text box with today's date and should also hide the calendar control and display the image button.

I hope that someone can help me sort out what I am doing wrong and help me get to the correct solution. Not really happy with the outcome so far.

My code-behind:

```
Partial Class Request
    Inherits Page

Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton1

Protected Sub Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    Label.Text = "Current date: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
    Label.Text = "Selected date: " + Calendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString()

    Dim label1 = System.DateTime.Now
    Dim label2 = SelectedDate
    Dim ImageButton1 = ImageButton1
End Sub

protected void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblday.Text = Calendar1.TodaysDate.ToShortDateString();
    lblbday.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
}

' Display using current (en-us) culture's short date format 
Dim ddlDate As Date = #3/15/2008#

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load
   Calendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
   Label.Text = "Today's date and time is :" + Calendar.SelectedDate;
   Calendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Me.clnArrival = thisDate.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Sub Submit(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    TextBox1.Text = "The date and time is " & Now()
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlDay_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   EventArgs) Handles ddlDay.SelectedIndexChanged
    clnArrival.Visible = False
    Dim day As String = ddlDay.SelectedItem.Text(ddlDay.SelectedValue)
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMonth.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim month As String = ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)
End Sub

 Protected Sub clnArrival_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles clnArrival.SelectionChanged
    ddlMonth_SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Month.ToString
    ddlDay_SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Day.ToString
    clnArrival.Visible = True
End Sub
End Class
```

My markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Request.aspx.vb" Inherits="Request" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Chapter 6: Reservations</title>
    <link href="Styles/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Request.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script language="VB" runat="server">
        Sub Page_Load()
            Response.Write("Today is: ")
        End Sub
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="page">
        <h1>Royal Inn and Suites</h1>
        <h2>Where you&rsquo;re always treated like royalty</h2>
        <p id="arrival_date">
            Arrival date:&nbsp;

        <asp:Calendar ID = "Calendar" runat = "server" SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar_SelectionChanged" SelectedDate="1/1/0001" VisibleDate="1/1/0001">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" ImageUrl="C:\aspnet4_vb\Jeanne Tatro Webs 424 - HW 6 - Ch06Reservation\Images\Calendar.bmp" />
        </asp:Calendar>
        </p>
        <p class="clear">
            Number of nights:&nbsp; 
        </p>
        <p>
            Number of adults:&nbsp;
            Children:&nbsp;
        </p>
        <h3>Preferences</h3>
        <p>
            Room type:&nbsp;
        </p>
        <p>
            Bed type:&nbsp;
        </p>
        <p id="requests">Special requests:</p>
        <h3 class="clear">Contact information</h3>
        <p class="contact">Name:</p>
        <p class="contact">Email:</p>
        <p id="buttons"></p>
        <p id="message"></p>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing VB.NET and C# code, don't you get a compiler error?

Comment: Also your images source is a local file, what will not work on the server. Use server relative path instead, e.g. /Images/Bla.jpeg

Comment: Also don't mix code-behind and in-line code, that's a bad style, that adds ambiguously and decreases readability and maintainability.